# Java URLClassNotFoundException over mounted Isilon connection

Tags: java, classpath, mount

I am having trouble with mounted filesystems running a Blackboard Java application.  We migrated resources from a VNX filesystem to an Isilon system.  There is a mounted /content directory over which the local java must reach to access classes.  When the older VNX system is connected the script / application run fine, but when the Isilon system is connected, the application breaks with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Lists
        at blackboard.apps.bbpatch.cli.CliLauncher.<clinit>(CliLauncher.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Lists
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 1 more
```

As implied by the above summary, it's not a problem of not being in the classpath or the classpath being incorrectly specified.  There is something in the data communication that must be tripping up this interaction, perhaps some kind of delay issue?

I am seeking advice on how to debug this problem.

Thank you

Comment: I assume you copied the files over from the old filesystem to the new filesystem? How did you do that?

Comment: The system admin first used rsync, then a straight copy and verified the paths are identical in files and all other variables - owner mode etc.

Comment: I'd suggest double checking the jar that contains the Google library mentioned in the stack trace nonetheless. Running something like md5sum on it on the old and new filesystems would ensure that there was no corruption during transfer.

Comment: Thanks.  We'll look into that, but now I wonder about this library being remote - not on our server at all - I'll get back shortly

Comment: The files are identical.  I found that by adding a jar to the classpath, JVM found the class but a new classnotfound error was thrown. I stopped after a few jar file entries because that's the wrong approach of course.  These are not redundant classes. The problem too is this is Blackboard's Java code and I cannot modify it.  Is there a good tutorial/howto on Java debugging / logging you know of?